# Nextjs build output still showing Pages Router after migration to App Router

Tags: next.js, build, app-router

I've recently migrated all the routes on my project from pages router to app router.
I no longer have a pages folder.
The build output is still showing the pages router, 404 route.

[Build output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0FIC.png)

```
Route (pages)                               Size     First Load JS

─ o /404                                   202 B          86.6 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all              86.4 kB
  - chunks/framework-a92791af35b6cd55.js   45.1 kB
  - chunks/main-73ee2d915f58a0d1.js        28 kB
  - chunks/pages/_app-514ed2a69a71f9b0.js  210 B
  - chunks/webpack-63b34cf7686a351b.js     13.1 kB
```

I was expecting that part of the output to disappear completely.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that I observe a similar build output for my projects using only the App router.

I assume this expected behavior, as Next is migrating from the Pages to the App router. I would expect this to disappear eventually.